# Streamwriter is clearing the text from my text file then updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamwriter, streamwriter.write

I'm trying to get my streamwriter to add text onto the end of the text file but for some reason, it is just replacing the text with whatever I have entered. Any help is appreciated to fix this.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/blogMessages.txt");
sw.WriteLine(postTextBox.Text);
sw.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a over ridden method for stream writer

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/blogMessages.txt", true);
```

this will apppend your text

Comment: So i pretty much just add 'true' onto the end. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the overload version of the [StreamWriter constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) that take an extra parameter to configure overwrite or append to the stream. And please [add the using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~") + 
                        "/App_Data/blogMessages.txt", true))
{

     sw.WriteLine(postTextBox.Text);

}
```

The using statement allows for the correct close and dispose of the stream also in case you get an exception when opening or writing

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 using (System.IO.TextWriter tw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\TEMP\IEALog\path.txt", true))
        {
            tw.WriteLine(message + "Source ;- " + source + "StackTrace:- " + exc.StackTrace.ToString());
        }
```